# How to override some property in the class under test during unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

I have a class that I would like to test with Unit tests. It has some logic to look for some values in the local xml file, and if the value is not found it will read some external source (SqlServer DB). But during Unit testing I don't want this component to interact with Sql Server at all. During unit testing I would like to replace SqlServer implementation of the External source reader to some Noop reader. What is the good approach to achieve that? Important note: I can't define constructor that accepts instance of reader type since it is client facing API and I want to limit what they can do with my classes. 
I am currently using few ways in Unit tests:

- Use reflection to set value of the private/protected property to my mocked implementation of the reader
- Define factory that will create concrete class. Register factory in Unity container & class under test will get factory object from DI container and instantiate reader according to my needs
- Subclass class-under-test and set property there.

But none of them seem to be clean enough to me. Are there any better ways to achieve that?
Here is the sample code to demonstrate example of the class-under-the-test:

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public class SomeDataReader
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> store = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // I need to override what this property does
        private readonly IExternalStoreReader ExternalStore = new SqlExternalStoreReader(null, false, new List<string>() {"blah"});


        public string Read(string arg1, int arg2, bool arg3)
        {
            if (!store.ContainsKey(arg1))
            {
                return ExternalStore.ReadSource().ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    internal interface IExternalStoreReader
    {
        object ReadSource();
    }

    // This 
    internal class SqlExternalStoreReader : IExternalStoreReader
    {
        public SqlExternalStoreReader(object arg1, bool arg2, List<string> arg3)
        {

        }

        public object ReadSource()
        {
            using (var db = new SqlConnection("."))
            {
                return new object();    
            }
        }
    }

    internal class NoOpExternalStoreReader : IExternalStoreReader
    {
        public object ReadSource()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var objectToTest = new SomeDataReader();
            objectToTest.Read("", -5, false); // This will try to read DB, I don't want that.
        }
    }
```

Comment: See http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, which exposes all internal members to [friend assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx).

You could start by creating a separate `internal` constructor overload, which can accept a different instance of `IExternalStoreReader`:

```
public class SomeDataReader
{
    // publicly visible
    public SomeDataReader()
        : this(new SqlExternalStoreReader(...))
    { }

    // internally visible
    internal SomeDataReader(IExternalStoreReader storeReader)
    {
        ExternalStore = storeReader;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then allow the unit testing assembly to access internal members by adding the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to your `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourUnitTestingAssembly")]
```

If you're really concerned about people trying to access your internal members, you can also use [strong naming](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/using-internalsvisibleto-attribute-with-strong-named-assemblies) with the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to ensure no one tries to impersonate your unit testing assembly.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: change your code. Because you have a private readonly field that creates its own value, you cannot change that behaviour without getting really hacky, if at all. So instead, don't do it that way. Change the code to:

```
public class SomeDataReader
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> store = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private readonly IExternalStoreReader externalStore;

    public SomeDataReader(IExternalStoreReader externalStore)
    {
        this.externalStore = externalStore;
    }
```

In other words, inject the `IExternalStoreReader` instance into the class. That way you can create a `noop` version for unit tests and the real one for production code.

Comment: agree, that would make life much easier, but that signature will see this class users and I don't want them to see and use it (this class is part of the library that we ship to other teams that use our service)

Comment: Do the clients of your library really need to new up SomeDataReader objects? Alternatively you can use property injection instead of contructor injection (i.e. in your unit tests do myDataReader.InitializeExternalStore(fakeStore)). If you don't completely want to expose the private field, look into [subclass to test](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SubclassToTest) to make the property settable in tests only.

Comment: @VitaliyGanzha, the class is `public`, so users of the API can see and use it. So I'm unsure what the issue is with injecting an instance of an interface into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling the complete code yourself, you could create a fake `SqlExternalStoreReader` with a stubbed implementation inside your unit test project.
This stub implementation allows you to access all fields and forward calls to your mocking framework/unit test